# Excel File is [Read Only] file: How to change it so edits can be made to the excel file?

Tags: python, vba, excel

I am running a code where an excel will be saved into another directory and it works. My problem is it changes to a read only file and if I want to make a change to the file, I have to resave it with a new name. Is there a way to make it so edits can be made to the excel file that is being saved into the F drive? Because the rest of my code is dependent on the file in the PATH. So if I change data in excel file, I have to change name of excel file and the rest of my code will just read the data from the original file.

```
PATH='F:\Ten Year Load Forecasts.xlsm'
Master_Copy='I:\Ten Year Load Forecasts.xlsm'

if os.path.isfile(PATH) and os.access(PATH, os.R_OK):
    #print ('File exists and is readable')
    xlApp = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application') # Running Excel
    xlsPath = os.path.expanduser(PATH)# Reading xlsm file
    wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename=xlsPath) # Opening file
    xlApp.Run('csvfile3')# Running macro---- csvfile3 is the macro name. It is under the "csv" module in the VBA editor
    #wb.Save()
    #wb.close()

    xlApp.Quit()

else:
    #copyfile(Master_Copy, PATH)

    "Save Master_Copy to Path"
    "Repeat Function From above with running macro"                         
    xlApp = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application') # Running Excel
    xlsPath = os.path.expanduser(Master_Copy)# Reading xlsm file
    wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename=xlsPath) # Opening file
    xlApp.Run('csvfile4')# Running macro---- csvfile3 is the macro name. It is under the "csv" module in the VBA editor
    #wb.Save()
    xlApp.Quit()
    #wb.close()
```

-
This is the csv file 4 VBA code

```
Sub csvfile4()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "F:\Ten Year Load Forecasts 2017-2026.xlsm", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PSSE_Export_Data").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="F:\Load_Forecasts.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifiying "ReadOnlyRecommended:=False" when saving the workbook. Such as...

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _ 
"F:\Ten Year Load Forecasts 2017-2026.xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled _ 
, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _ 
CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: @ R Hamilton   What is Password for?

Comment: it just states there is no password, not strictly needed.